# Shared library in Telegram Android App

Tags: telegram

[This](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/tree/master/TMessagesProj/libs) libraries are loaded by the app, but what do they do? I search in google the library name but there is nothing about how it is compiled

Answer (score 0):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but those are libraries for different cpu architectures. `.so` files are standalone libraries that are linked at compile time, **not** compiled. As far as what they do, they're probably just for allowing different mobile platform compatabilities.

Comment: I understand that are libraries for different architectures, but why Telegram need those? Is there something missing in Android? Do those libraries declare new classes or functions?, and if so, which are the functions/classes that those libraries declare?